# Python bottle cookies issue on GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, session-cookies, bottle

Am new to the bottle framework but we want to use it for a project which we are working on. This is the code causing the error. This is my full code in my file.
I can add the imported modules also if need arises
`

```
import model
import sessionDAO
import userDAO
import bottle
import re
import cgi
import logging

@bottle.route('/')
def index_page():
    cookie  = bottle.request.get_cookie('session',path='/')
    username = sessions.get_username(cookie)
    return bottle.template('blog_template', dict(username=username))

@bottle.get('/signup')
def signup():
    return bottle.template('signup',dict(username="", password="",
                                password_error="",
                                email="", username_error="", email_error="",
                                verify_error =""))

@bottle.get('/login')
def login():
    return bottle.template('login', dict(username='',password='', login_error=''))


@bottle.get('/welcome')
def welcome():
    cookie =  bottle.request.get_cookie('session',path='/')
    username = sessions.get_username(cookie)

    if username is None:
        print "welcome cant verify/identify user, sending you to the signup page"
        bottle.redirect('/signup')

    return bottle.template('welcome',dict(username=username))

@bottle.get('/internal_error')
@bottle.view('error_template')
def internal_error():
    return dict(error='System encountered a DB error ')

@bottle.get('/logout')
def logout():
    cookie = bottle.request.get_cookie('session',path='/')
    sessions.end_session(cookie)
    bottle.response.set_cookie('session','', path='/')
    bottle.redirect('/signup')

@bottle.post('/login')
def process_login():
    username = bottle.request.forms.get('username')
    password = bottle.request.forms.get('password')

    print "user submitted ", username, "pass ", password

    user_record = users.validate_login(username,password)

    if user_record:
        session_id = sessions.start_session(user_record.id)

        if session_id is None:
            print "internal error"
            bottle.redirect('/internal_error')
        cookie = session_id

        bottle.response.set_cookie('session',cookie, path='/')

        bottle.redirect('/welcome')

    else:
        return bottle.template('login', dict(username=cgi.escape(username),password="",login_error="Invalid Login"))

@bottle.post('/signup')
def register():
    username = bottle.request.forms.get('username')
    password = bottle.request.forms.get('password')
    email = bottle.request.forms.get('email')
    verify = bottle.request.forms.get('verify')
    errors = {'username':username,'email':email}
    if validate_signup(username,password,verify,email,errors):

        if not users.add_user(username,password,email):
            errors['username_error'] = "User already Exist"
            return bottle.template('signup',errors)
        session_id = sessions.start_session(username)
        print session_id
        bottle.response.set_cookie('session', session_id, path='/')
        bottle.redirect('/welcome')
    else:
        print "User did not validate"
        return bottle.template('signup',errors)



def validate_signup(username,password,verify,email,errors):
    USER_RE = re.compile(r"^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,20}$")
    PASS_RE = re.compile(r"^.{6,20}$")
    EMAIL_RE = re.compile(r"^[\S]+@[\S]+\.[\S]+$")


    errors['username_error'] = ""
    errors['password_error'] = ""
    errors['verify_error'] = ""
    errors['email_error'] = ""


    if not USER_RE.match(str(username)):
        errors['username_error'] = "Invalid username, try letters and numbers only"
        return False

    if not PASS_RE.match(str(password)):
        errors['password_error'] = "Invalid password"
        return False

    if password != str(verify):
        errors['verify_error']  = 'Password must match'
        return False
    if email != "":
        if not EMAIL_RE.match(str(email)):
            errors['email_error'] = 'Invalid email address'
            return False

    return True

@bottle.error(500)
def error500(error):
    logging.debug(str(error))
    print str(error)
    bottle.redirect('/signup')
#   return bottle.template('error_template',dict(error=str(error)))



user_data = model.User
session_data = model.Session
users = userDAO.UserDAO(user_data)
sessions = sessionDAO.SessionDAO(session_data)

app = bottle.app()
```

`
the set cookie is not working even if I remove the path args..

Comment: You're missing a piece of your code. Please update with full code.

Comment: I have update the full code